# array_slice() warning in php and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote this code:

```
function get_feed(){

 // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
$rss = fetch_rss('http://dorar.shamekh.ws/?feed=rss2');
$maxitems = 1;
$items = array_slice($rss->items, 0, $maxitems,false);
return $items;

}
```

As a part of a plugin for WordPress , it works fine on my local server , but when I upload it to my blog I get the message:

> Warning: array_slice() 
>   [function.array-slice]: The first 
>   argument should be an array in

php version on my local host : `5.2.6`

php version on my site : `5.2.5`

Comment: What does fetch_rss do on failure? Does it return a valid object? Is $rss->items an array when it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the documentation that `$rss->items` should already be an array. I'd guess that the RSS fetch is failing. Try:

```
if (is_array($rss->items)) {
   $items = array_slice($rss->items, 0, $maxitems,false);
} else { var_dump($rss->items); }
```

MagpieRSS combined with dorar.shamekh.ws' (use of/configuration of) Apache 1.3.41 is leading to a very bizarre behaviour:

A "normal" HTTP request:

```
GET /feed/ HTTP/1.0
Host: dorar.shamekh.ws
```

MagpieRSS's request:

```
GET /feed/ HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: MagpieRSS/0.72 (+http://magpierss.sf.net)
Host: dorar.shamekh.ws:80
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, */*
```

Note the different 'Host' headers. When the port number is appended, as in MagpieRSS, the site returns a 301:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 22 May 2009 02:45:03 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.41 (Unix) PHP/5.2.5 mod_auth_passthrough/1.8 mod_log_bytes/1.2 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_ssl/2.8.31 OpenSSL/0.9.7a
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.5
X-Pingback: http://dorar.shamekh.ws/xmlrpc.php
Last-Modified: Wed, 20 May 2009 22:03:05 GMT
ETag: "e591693fdf2d27ee7dae19e256db2f46"
Location: http://dorar.shamekh.ws/feed/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: When I try to load the given URL using MagpieRSS locally, I get:
Warning: MagpieRSS: Failed to fetch http://dorar.shamekh.ws/?feed=rss2 (HTTP Response: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Comment: NULL                            -------------

Comment: yes its working now , i change the rss link and it work , but I'm still shocked because the old rss link work in my local server

Comment: See above - I'm not really sure which end is at fault here, but the behaviour is at least explainable. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about casting $rss->items as an array first:

```
function get_feed(){

 // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
$rss = fetch_rss('http://dorar.shamekh.ws/?feed=rss2');
$maxitems = 1;
$rss->items = (array) $rss->items;
$items = array_slice($rss->items, 0, $maxitems,false);
return $items;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like to me that when it is attempting to get the RSS it is failing. Perhaps `fetch_rss` uses file_get_contents which has been disabled for URLs.

Either that, or for some reason, the property $rss->items isn't an array for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_rss()` it's deprecated. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_rss

You must use `fetch_feed()`